# What does a single 'binding' mean in a XAML label?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

The acceptecd answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156840/how-to-make-only-the-header-of-the-tabitem-respond-to-the-mouse-event) explains how a double click event can be realized for a `TabItem`.

I understand the approach except of one thing: `<Label Content={Binding}>`

What exactly does `{Binding}` mean here for the labels content?

Comment: Do you mean "I understand"?  Or "I don't understand"?  Should you edit this?

Answer (score 3):

From [`Binding.Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.path(v=vs.110).aspx)

> ... period (.) path can be used to **bind to the current source**. For example, Text="{Binding}" is equivalent to Text="{Binding Path=.}"

which means it will bind whole object that is currently available in `DataContext` which then will be converted for display using default or custom template

**EDIT**

In this case `TabItem` hosts `ContentPresenter` with `ContentSource` set to `Header` which changes `DataContext` to whatever is currently available in `Header` therefore `DataContext` for `Label` will be set to `string` as defined in `Header`

[image]